# cannot get localStorage to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Here is my fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/XR8EZ](http://jsfiddle.net/XR8EZ)

I cannot get the save data to load after clicking the load button. Can anyone help me here?

Sorry for the length =D

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net demo of the whole code in action and post only the relevant code to the question/problem, please.

Comment: @JaredFarrish--heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XR8EZ/ 
Sorry about that. My question applies to the save and load buttons. The goal is to save the state of the canvas (images/shapes/etc) and be able to load it on a different viewing. Please help.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas--heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XR8EZ/ 
Sorry about that. My question applies to the save and load buttons. The goal is to save the state of the canvas (images/shapes/etc) and be able to load it on a different viewing. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load routine is wrong.
You save all your datas (stringifyed) with setItem('serializedObj').
Then you retrieve value with "retrievedItem = localStorage.getItem('serializedObj');" but not save the value of "JSON.parse(retrievedItem);".
Then you try to retrieve values directly by localStorage.getItem(imgName);

You retrive and save data parded:

```
dataparsed = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
```

Then you must use this value for retrieving values:

```
//Reconstruct the original image array
for (i=0;i<totalState.length;i++) {                        
  var thisParseImgVal = dataparsed.imgName;    
  totalImage[i] = JSON.parse(thisParseImgVal);
}
```

You have to correct you save/load code, I suggest you to save you data as array:

```
var imgVal = JSON.stringify(totalImage);                        
var shpVal = JSON.stringify(totalShape);
var hLval = JSON.stringify(totalHighlight);
var str = {imgName:imgVal,shpName:shpVal,hLname:hLval}; //Store
```

So you must read it as:

```
totalImage[i] = JSON.parse(thisParseImgVal[i]);
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` in the editor to markup inline and block code. This helps immensely with readability. `:)`

Comment: @InuYaksa--i see you removed my `str` bucket obj `(str = str + {...})`. Any reason for this?

Comment: if you directly stringify the array, you don't need to use the loop.

Comment: @InuYaksa--i tried your example, but i cannot get the stored data to load. However, these objects **are** being stored. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: using debug tool (like firebug) check if getItem retuns your datas (I like use console.log to display datas). Then you must check what parse returns (it must return your object). And so on...

Comment: @InuYaksa--`imgName` is coming up undefined. I define it and store it in the save function. any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I need to check you code, can you make a jfiddle page with only save/load code?

Comment: @InuYaksa--i am going to move this dicussion to chat. see you there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5966/discussion-between-codeninja-and-inuyaksa)